# Kohana Database Configuration System

Tags: kohana, kohana-3, kohana-orm, kohana-db

I am trying to get the database configuration functionality working with kohana 3.2. I want to attach the Config_Database as source:

```
Kohana::$config->attach(new Config_Database, False);
```

Described here: http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/kohana/config
I attach the new source after loading the modules (so the database module is loaded before attaching the source). But when I have attached the new source it seems as if kohana does not want to load any controller using the Auth module with ORM driver. Then the browser loads and loads but only a white page appears. All other controller, not using the ORM or Auth module, function properly.

Can anyone give a short explanation how to use the Config_Database functionality, or give a alternative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update ORM module to 3.2/develop

Comment: Will give it a try next time, for now i have set up my own mysql config system...